# VSCode variable for OS-independent list separator in environment variables

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to concatenate a search path to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in an OS-independent way. On Windows the list separator is `;`, but on unix-like systems it is `:`.

I want to have something like this in my `launch.json`

```
"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/path-to-package${env_var_list_separator}${env:PYTHONPATH}"}
```

What is the variable for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) v1.7.0 contains the command `extension.commandvariable.envListSep`

You use it in `task.json` and `launch.json` as

```
${command:extension.commandvariable.envListSep}
```