# How can I add multiple values to a PATH environment variable definition in my integrated terminal configurations in VS Code?

Tags: json, windows, visual-studio-code, path, settings

I am trying to work with manim (a math animation library), and it requires the path to ffmpeg, which is stored in a different location then my other libraries. How can I extend my settings.json in VS Code to include multiple paths?

My current settings.json file:

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PATH": "C:\\Users\\Computer_User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Scripts"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that for Windows, you just do something like this:

```json
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PATH": "foo;bar;baz"
}
```

Where `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` are paths.

The semicolon is Windows' separator character for entries in `PATH` environment variables. For UNIX systems, use colons instead.

You can add [`${env:PATH}`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables) to the list if you want to include the `PATH` that is in the environment of the VS Code instance running the integrated terminal.

If you want an OS-independent variable to use, see [VSCode variable for OS-independent list separator in environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64633223/11107541).